# Resign decrypted ipa with adhoc provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, adhoc

I wanted to resign a decrypted ipa with an adhoc profile by me. I changed the bundle id of the decrypted ipa to an own bundle id *(com.example.decripa)*. I registered that bundle id in my developer portal and created an adhoc provisioning profile from that. I downloaded it and used [iReSign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) to resign the decrypted ipa. The parameters in iReSign:

**ipa:** the decrypted ipa *(DecrIpa.ipa)*

**provisioning profile:** the adhoc provisioning profile I created *(DecrIpa.mobileprovision)*

**entitlements.plist**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>developerID.com.example.decripa</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>developerID.com.example.decripa</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After that I created the other necessary files using [BetaBuilder](https://github.com/HunterHillegas/iOS-BetaBuilder) and uploaded them to my website. The process using BetaBuilder worked for other apps (by me) where I could archive them for adhoc use right out of Xcode.

But if I downloaded the manifest.plist the app would install but be greyed out. There was no option to trust the developer in settings.

I only have a normal developer account and not an enterprise account.

How can I resign a decrypted ipa for adhoc use? I have no access to the project, only to the ipa.

Thank you for your help!

---

PS: All italic written IDs and names are not real, I just used them here to make things easier.

PPS: I added my UDID to the adhoc provisioning profile, as I said, the process already worked for another app (by me) where I could archive it for adhoc use right out of Xcode.

---

**EDIT:** Here is the system log: [The system log](https://wytemusic.de/syslog.txt)

Comment: Can you post the device console output from when you attempt to download and install the app on a device?  That would help understand what is actually failing.

Comment: How can I log that? I just install it via ota via safari. Should I connect it to Xcode and somehow log the devices console? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, plug the device into your Mac and fire up Xcode. Go to the Devices window and select the device.  You'll see the console for the device at the bottom.  Watch for errors when you try to install on the device from Safari.

Comment: `Jun 18 13:02:05 iPhone-von-Oscar installd(MobileSystemServices)[44] <Notice>: 0x17deef000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL:withOptions:error:]: 147: Failed to verify code signature of /private/var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.Yh20eK/extracted/Payload/ppsideloader.app : 0xe8008016 (The executable was signed with invalid entitlements.)` - Something is not right with your entitlements.  Is this some other company's app?

Comment: Yes it is. It is a ++ (plus plus) version of an app by unlimapps. But I heard that they are not encrypted. I downloaded the tweaked ipa and only changed the bundle ID as explained in my question

Comment: And thank you very much for checking the log! I mean it’s very long and thank you for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use this mac application for resigning your ipa with new certificate and provisioning or different bundle identifier. I have successfully resign on xcode 8.3

Link: https://github.com/DanTheMan827/ios-app-signer